# Making div look more like site linked to without copying source code direct?

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is my current HTML code (details changed for privacy):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8" />
 <style>
 body {
 font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
 font-size: 13px;
 }
 p {
 display: table-cell;
 }
 img {
 height: 204px;
 float: left;
 }
 div.content-magazine {
 display: table;
 }
 div.content-usedcar {
 font-family: Trebuchet MS, Arial, sans-serif;
 font-size: 15px;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 padding: 10px;
 }
 </style>
 <title>Anytown Car Sales | No.1 in West Yorkshire since 1982</title>
</head>
<body>
<H1>Anytown Car Sales</H1>
<H2>Est.1982</H2>
<H3>Sutton-in-Craven, West Yorkshire BD20</H3>
<H3>Tel: 01535 000000</H3>
<div class="content-magazine">
<div class="content-usedcar">
<img src="http://media.autoweek.nl/m/4cfy7lsbkrs1.jpg">
<P>2018 68 VAUXHALL INSIGNIA 1.5 TURBO 165 ELITE NAV, 5 door, blue, 15,000 miles £POA</P>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I have been trying to do is to make a DIV that looks similar to the list at https://www.britanniacarsales.co.uk/used-cars with the picture next to the vehicle and space in between divs (color of my website's body will be changed in the code) but I am not quite sure how to get it to look *similar* if not the same.

What changes should I make to the code so that div class content-usedcar looks like the style in the link I've used as inspiration from? (I'm trying to make this original work, not copying others' CSS).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <style>
    body {
      font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
      font-size: 13px;
    }
    p {
      vertical-align: top;
      margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    }
    img {
      vertical-align: top;
      height: 204px;
    }
    div.content-usedcar {
      display: flex;
      font-family: Trebuchet MS, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 15px;
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
      padding: 10px;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Anytown Car Sales | No.1 in West Yorkshire since 1982</title>
</head>
<body>
<H1>Anytown Car Sales</H1>
<H2>Est.1982</H2>
<H3>Sutton-in-Craven, West Yorkshire BD20</H3>
<H3>Tel: 01535 000000</H3>
<div class="content-magazine">
  <div class="content-usedcar">
    <img src="http://media.autoweek.nl/m/4cfy7lsbkrs1.jpg">
    <P>2018 68 VAUXHALL INSIGNIA 1.5 TURBO 165 ELITE NAV, 5 door, blue, 15,000 miles £POA</P>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

how about this?